# Android Application Crashes when i start an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Hi guys i have already seen the posts and questions earlier but none was my issue nor the suggested solutions have solved my problem.
I have written a login page code that has a signup button that should take me to another activity which is the sign up activity
the XML for the button is as follows

`<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/signup"
        android:id="@+id/singupText"
        android:onClick="signUp"
        android:textColor="#093ff2"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#00ffffff" />`

and the onclick method in my main activity where the button is is

```
public void signUp(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, signup.class);
    MainActivity.this.finish();
    startActivity(i);
}
```

my logs are as follows

```
12-28 22:37:53.533 29835-29835/com.example.alloush.pesticides E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.alloush.pesticides, PID: 29835
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alloush.pesticides/com.example.alloush.pesticides.signup}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:827)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:751)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                                                                                at com.example.alloush.pesticides.signup.onCreate(signup.java:20)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:827) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:751) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
                                                                                at com.example.alloush.pesticides.signup.onCreate(signup.java:20) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
                                                                                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3054)
                                                                                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                                                                                at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3694)
                                                                                at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3624)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:474)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:236)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:827) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:751) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
                                                                                at com.example.alloush.pesticides.signup.onCreate(signup.java:20) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried launching the singup intent independently to check if it is all going well and it worked perfectly... however i tried launching another activity the same thing happened the app crashes and the error and the logs...
Any suggestions for my case ?

Comment: Are you trying to include a very large image file in your layout somewhere?

Comment: Can you share the entire layout  XML file?

Comment: Try the following - Do in android manifest do `android:largeheap=true ` or maybe remove the finish before starting the intent

Comment: thank you guys problem solved... check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ImageView in your layout, check your drawable/background_main i.e. the background image of your root layout - the VM runs out of memory when decoding the bitmap. Make the image dimensions smaller.  So best way is to reduce it size or resolution.

Comment: Thank you sir this solved my problem. When i removed the background of the other XML layout it worked perfectly and then i reduced the image dimensions and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Call the finish method last.

```
public void signUp(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, signup.class);
    startActivity(i);
    MainActivity.this.finish();
    // or just write
    //finish();
}
```

Comment: thank you fro your concern however this line of code did not contain the problem... it was with the dimensions of the image as @oalpayli mentioned in his answer

Answer (score 0):

your logCat displays some errors.

this error tells that your signup class does not exists. Have you declared your activity at manifest file and please follow java naming rules to name a class file-> First Character is capital.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alloush.pesticides/com.example.alloush.pesticides.signup}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

error at line 20 in signup activity.

```
at com.example.alloush.pesticides.signup.onCreate(signup.java:20)
```

some kind of view inflate error

```
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
```

this inflate error may be due to your xml file

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Comment: Hello Ankush. While answering please maintain a respectful tone and don't be patronizing. There is no need to start with phrases like "Hey buddy, Do you know how to read this?". Also, While this answer might explain the error it does not provide the solution. Ask the OP for more information if you need it to find the exact problem and solve it. Cheers!

Comment: hello Ankush, the problem was not in here since the other layout worked perfectly when i made it a launcher activity which means that the problem was in inflating the other layout in addition that the XML files and all java files are flawless of errors or the compiler will not allow the app to run or build. The VM was running out of memory when trying to process large image dimensions i have used i.e 1200x1600 so i converted it to 800x600 and it worked perfectlly...